# How to Invoke delayed_job_active_record (rake jobs:work) externally production env

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, production-environment

I have a delayed job which is called whenever a user posts a song, this job sends an activity post to the users Facebook wall. Here is the code for the job and calling it in the controller.

I am using the `'delayed_job_active_record'` gem as seen in  [Ryan Bates Facebook Open Graph Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/363-facebook-open-graph)

user.rb

```
def self.post_song(user_id, song_url)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    user.facebook.put_connections("me", "virtual_piano:post", song: song_url)
  end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
(upon successful save)
        User.delay.post_song(current_user.id, post_url(@post))
```

This job is run in development mode with the standard `rake jobs:work`.

I have seen some people using `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start` with delayed job
How could i invoke this method in production and keep it running in the background?

many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rake jobs:work` in delayed_job is like the `rails s` command for rails - it runs in the main process of the console (shell) that executed the command.  Meaning it stops running when the console(shell) containing it stops running (i.e. you log out).

You'll want to run `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start` instead - that starts the delayed_job queue as a daemon (background process) like `rails s -n` does for rails.

Answer (score 2):

The script does:

```
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

That will run the delayed_job in the background.

If you want to run in in the foreground, you can create a simple script that will have:

```
worker = Delayed::Worker.new({}) # or add options
worker.start
```